# How can I default objects?

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, shorthand

I want to do the equivalent of...

```
//Nonsensical
config.items=[Ext.create('Foo.register.AccountTypeForm',{config:arguments.hidden=true})];

//works ofc, but it looks untidy
arguments.hidden=true;
config.items=[Ext.create('Foo.register.AccountTypeForm',{config:arguments})];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do this?

```
config.items=[Ext.create('Foo.register.AccountTypeForm',
 {config:{hidden:true}})];
```

Or do you need reference the arguments object again later?

Comment: Just tossing around default params, so exactly what i needed, thanks.